# android margins not working when dynamically inserting views

Tags: android, dynamic, margins

I have a simple view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/contact_selected"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="3dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Billy Bob"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I statically copy the LinearLayout markup into my main activity layout, the margins are as expected.  However, when I add the view into the main activity layout dynamically, the margins are ignored.  Here's how I insert the view

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);
TextView txt_title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
txt_title.setText("Dynamic #1");
llayout.addView(view, llayout.getChildCount()-1);

View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);
txt_title = (TextView)view2.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
txt_title.setText("Dynamic #2");
llayout.addView(view2, llayout.getChildCount()-1);
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

The container in the main layout is a LinearLayout, which is a child of a HorizontalScrollView.  Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

When dynamically adding views, you shouldn't inflate the `View` with a `null` `ViewGroup` parent.  So, in other words you should be using `inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, linearLayout, false);`. The parent is used when determining what type of layout parameters to generate.  Pass your parent container (in this case, your linear layout), so it correctly instantiates the [ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html) from your XML.

Comment: Thanks, this is a clean solution, and is my preferred way of doing it.  For anyone else learning this stuff, note that because inflate(view,parent) inflates the view INTO the parent (appends as last child), the line in my test code where I add the view (i.e. llayout.addView()) will cause an error because the view has already been inserted.

In my case I need to maintain a fixed view as the last child, and insert new children in front of it.  So I remove my last view before the inflate() and add it back after the inflate().  Works like a charm.

Comment: @JohnWard actually you still need the addView if you use "inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, linearLayout, false)" with that last boolean parameter.

Comment: @Flyview true. but also it allows you to insert the view to the index you want later

Answer (score 6):

This happens because you need to give "**Margin**" to layouts dynamically. You can do this by creating an object of "**LayoutPrams**", like this:-

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);
```

Here , you can set the **LayoutParams** to the linearlayout:

```
ll.addView(okButton, layoutParams);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm changing the approved answer to the one offered by Submersed.  Your answer was useful and taught me something I didn't know, but his answer is cleaner and doesn't force me to calc dips for the margins.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback John.

Comment: I'd like to know why it is like so? Why they can't just be set in the layout file?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to get display density.
related docs are  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

and get ID which you want set margin view.
for my case,

```
layout_login_box = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.login_layout_box);

float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)layout_login_box.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins((int) (24  * density),0,(int) (24  * density),(int) (16  * density));
layout_login_box.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Also, you can change ConstraintLayout to your own view.